# Delay of achievement dialog updating

Tags: bug, achievements-dialog

Yesterday I have earened reputation on 19:35. But the list of recent achievements still does not contain the change.

[image: achievements list]

Why is the delay so long?

Comment: Had the same thing a couple of weeks ago. Resolved itself after a few hours. Apparently a bug/glitch that happens from time to time, but not very high on the to-do list.

Comment: @m69, in my case the event have not appeared till now (3 days have passed).